# Can the first order condition of the lagrangian of a generic kernel ridge regression be solved in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I'm relatively new to `sympy` but would like to know the following. Suppose we have given a generic kernel ridge regression typ of optimization problem of the form

[image]

Is it possible for generic setup like this to use Sympy to get the solution for the first order condition (\nabla L=0).

Comment: It sounds like you want to use SymPy's MatrixSymbol. I can't offer a detailed answer because I don't fully understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks for you help. It is a bit hard to formulate the question without using LaTeX here on stackexchange. I will upload a picture with the detailed math explaining what I aim for a bit later today. hope this clarifies then things

Comment: @OscarBenjamin added a picture. Hope it makes more sense now that I would like to get all the equation of $\nabla L =0$

Comment: I think it is possible using `MatrixSymbol` if you can express the sum in terms of matrix operations rather than an explicit sum.

Comment: A few alternative approaches: use Jax to get the actual derivative or type your formula into wolfram alpha.